# The difference in lifetime between a function and a closure in Rust

Tags: rust

While trying to learn Rust I decided to try and use the `pathfinding` crate, specifically for the `bfs` algorithm to attempt to solve a toy [three jugs problem](https://programmierkonzepte.ch/engl/index.php?inhalt_links=navigation.inc.php&inhalt_mitte=effizienz/kuerzesterweg.inc.php). [The function signature for BFS](https://github.com/samueltardieu/pathfinding/blob/main/src/directed/bfs.rs#L66) is rather straightforward:

```
pub fn bfs<N, FN, IN, FS>(start: &N, successors: FN, success: FS) -> Option<Vec<N>>
where
    N: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    FN: FnMut(&N) -> IN,
    IN: IntoIterator<Item = N>,
    FS: FnMut(&N) -> bool,
```

Calling this function using a closure to generate the successors compiles successfully:

```
let capacities = [8,5,3];
let start_node = JugConfiguration::new([8,0,0], &capacities);
let goal_node = JugConfiguration::new([4,4,0], &capacities);

let result = bfs(&start_node, |p| p.pour_options(), |p| *p == goal_node);
```

However, calling it with a function that does the same work as the closure, fails to compile due to lifetime violations:

```
fn gen_jug_moves<'a>(node: &'a JugConfiguration<'a, 3>) -> Vec<JugConfiguration<'a, 3>> {
    node.pour_options()
}
[...]
let result = bfs(&start_node, gen_moves, |p| *p == goal_node);
```

The second version says that `capacities` must be borrowed for `'static` which of course it is not.

Why does the closure behave differently than the function? Is there a way to change the function lifetime declarations to behave like the closeure?

I'm probably missing something fundamental that I'm not even aware of. Any pointers to things I can read to be less ignorant on the matter are welcome.

Complete code (which is a bit messy due to me trying to figure out what is wrong):

```
use std::collections::{VecDeque, HashSet};
use std::hash::Hash;
extern crate pathfinding;
use pathfinding::prelude::bfs;



#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug)]
struct JugConfiguration<'a, const NUM_JUGS: usize> {
    levels: [usize; NUM_JUGS],
    capacities: &'a [usize; NUM_JUGS],
}

impl<'a, const NUM_JUGS: usize> JugConfiguration<'a, NUM_JUGS> {
    fn new(levels: [usize; NUM_JUGS], capacities: &'a [usize; NUM_JUGS]) -> Self {
        Self { levels, capacities }
    }

    fn get_capacity(&self, jug: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        if jug >= NUM_JUGS {
            None
        } else {
            Some(self.capacities[jug])
        }
    }

    fn get_level(&self, jug: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        if jug >= NUM_JUGS {
            None
        } else {
            Some(self.levels[jug])
        }
    }

    fn pour_options(&self) -> Vec<Self> {
        let mut options = Vec::new();

        for source in 0..NUM_JUGS {
            for dest in 0..NUM_JUGS {
                if source == dest {
                    continue;
                }

                if let Some(source_level) = self.get_level(source) {
                    if let Some(dest_capacity) = self.get_capacity(dest) {
                        let dest_level = self.get_level(dest).unwrap_or(0);
                        let amount = dest_capacity - dest_level;

                        if amount > 0 {
                            let mut new_levels = self.levels.clone();

                            if source_level <= amount {
                                new_levels[dest] += source_level;
                                new_levels[source] = 0;
                            } else {
                                new_levels[dest] += amount;
                                new_levels[source] -= amount;
                            }

                            options.push(Self::new(new_levels, self.capacities));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        options
    }
}



fn gen_jug_moves<'a>(node: &'a JugConfiguration<'a, 3>) -> Vec<JugConfiguration<'a, 3>> {
    node.pour_options()
}

fn main() {
    let capacities = [8,5,3];
    let start_node = JugConfiguration::new([8,0,0], &capacities);
    let goal_node = JugConfiguration::new([4,4,0], &capacities);

    // Works:
    let result = bfs(&start_node, |p| p.pour_options(), |p| *p == goal_node);
    // Does not work:
    // let result = bfs(&start_node, gen_jug_moves, |p| *p == goal_node);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Disclaimer: Rust beginner, C++ background. Trying to work myself through the Rust book, please excuse (and correct) mistakes in my terminology. The intent of this question is to figure out what I don't understand, not to solve the toy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function signature and the signature inferred for the closure differ:

```rust
fn gen_jug_moves<'a>(node: &'a JugConfiguration<'a, 3>) -> Vec<JugConfiguration<'a, 3>>
```

vs something like the following for the closure

```rust
fn gen_jug_moves<'a, 'b>(node: &'a JugConfiguration<'b, 3>) -> Vec<JugConfiguration<'b, 3>>
```

I.e. you force two lifetimes to be the same that as you've noticed shouldn't be.
If you correct that it works with a function, too.

The lesson to learn is to start with distinct lifetimes for each and every position you could put one on the input and only assign the same lifetime to things that actually live for the same time.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure my understanding is correct, the issue here is that the reference to the JugConfiguration has a different lifetime than the Configuration itself. Hence the the difference in the input lifetimes. The output, configurations have the same lifetime as the input configuration because they borrow the same static value. Is this the correct way to think about this?

Comment: @Afiefh: I'm not sure your analysis here is correct. Sometimes I find useful to assign proper names to the lifetimes. For example the generic lifetime in `JugConfiguration` is actually the lifetime of the `capacities` member, not of the configuration itself. If you write `JugConfiguration<'capacities, NUM_JUGS>` then you can elide the other lifetime in the function with little confusion: `fn gen_jug_moves<'capacities>(node: &JugConfiguration<'capacities, 3>) -> Vec<JugConfiguration<'capacities, 3>>`.